# How to recover MailChimp Data after delete?

Tags: email

I accidentally Deleted an email from my list. It contains some data like conversations, notes, clicks,opens,etc. How can I recover these data from MailChimp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-subscribing the email solves half of my problem.

conversations, clicks and opens have restored but didn't get the notes associated with it.

Comment: still waiting for the exact answer for this. :)